# How to implement custom font in android

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, truetype

I am implementing a custom listview using custom array adpter. In each row, there is a text view and a image. I want to add custom font for arabic on the text view. can anyone help me load custom font. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is the code of MyViewHolder where i am creating the text view object :

```
public static class MyViewHolder {
    TextView textViewArabic;
    ImageView imgView;

    public MyViewHolder(View v, Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        textViewArabic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvArabic);
        imgView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? After all, since there are many, many existing answers for this (found by searching `android listview row font` on a search engine), you must have tried something and ran into problems.

Comment: @CommonsWare Dont you think that storing the font as a static variable in the `Application` subclass is a good idea because it will be used throughout? :) Initialize it in `onCreate()` and then use it everywhere

Comment: @LittleChild: It is something worth investigating. I'd be worried a bit about memory leaks, if `Typeface` happens to hold onto something that it shouldn't (e.g., some random `Context`). Also, I haven't measured the memory footprint of a `Typeface` instance to see if it is somehow tied to the number of glyphs in the font file. Outside of those concerns, though, a `Typeface` is something that ideally should be cached, particularly for a font file coming from assets, which definitely will not change for the lifetime of the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download a TruTypeFace font (.ttf) and place it in asset folder. Add following code to get that font from assets set that font to your text view like the code below.

```
public static class MyViewHolder {
  TextView textViewArabic;
  ImageView imgView;
  Typeface face;

  public MyViewHolder(View v, Context context) {
   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   textViewArabic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvArabic);
   imgView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
   face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/_PDMS_Saleem_QuranFont.ttf");
   textViewArabic.setTypeface(face);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:
   Inside `getView()` method

```
myHolder.textViewArabic.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
        "custom_font_file_name.ttf"););
```

Font file must be inside `assets/fonts/custom_font_file_name.ttf`

There is another way also by which you can override the fonts for entire layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below piece of code.

```
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font name.ttf");
TextView details = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_name);
details.setTypeface(font);
```

You need to store your font in the assets folder (src->main->assets)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In /res/layouts, you will need to include to-be-created custom text view in the activity_main.xml file.

/res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:customfontdemo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Standard Android Font" />

     <com.authorwjf.customfontdemo.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        customfontdemo:fontName="pipe_dream.ttf"
        android:text="Custom Android Font" />

</LinearLayout>
```

For more details, please refer [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-extend-androids-textview-to-use-custom-fonts/).